# Show/Hide Divs on Button Click: Not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The result: http://unidrones.co.za/PixieStudio/quotations.php

Simply put, I "Add New Tier" then "Remove Tier" then try adding it back, nothing happens. Here are the two JavaScript functions involved:

```
/*Remove Tier on Button Click*/
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0); //erase prices for this tier
    $(this).parent().hide();
    updateHandler();
});

/*Add New Tier on Button Click*/
$('#tier2, #tier3, #tier4, #tier5, #tier6').hide();
var count = 2, countMax = 6;
function addtier() {
  if(count > countMax) {
    return;
  }
  $('#tier' + count + '').fadeIn(1000);
  count++;
}
```

The HTML (abbreviated):

```
<div id="tier2">
<button type="button" class="button">Remove</button>
...
</div>

<div id="tier3">
<button type="button" class="button">Remove</button>
...
</div>

<div id="tier4">
<button type="button" class="button">Remove</button>
...
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to accurately explain this issue. You might understand if you go to that link and try adding/removing tiers.

Why won't the tiers reappear after I remove them?

Comment: Please include the source in your question.  External references have a habit of disappearing.  Question needs to be an [mcve]

Comment: the link seems to work for me. After adding 6th tier it stops adding, because of the counter

Comment: @Tibrogargan Okay I'll try to convert my code into a jsFiddle. I couldn't post everything here to make a working demo (it's quite a verbose code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a max count of 6—once you added all 6 tiers you run out of tiers to add, unless you reset the `count` variable again. What you should do is:

- increment the `count` whenever a tier is added
- **decrement the `count` whenever a tier is removed** (you're missing this part)

Also, instead of hiding them, you should remove them (using `.remove()`), so that you would not end up with duplicate IDs:

```
/*Track tiers*/
var count = 2, countMax = 6;

/*Remove Tier on Button Click*/
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    $(this).parent().remove();

    // Remember to decrement count!
    count--;

    // Optional: you might want to ensure that
    // count can go as low as 2, but not lower
    count = Math.max(2, count);

    updateHandler();
});

/*Add New Tier on Button Click*/
$('#tier2, #tier3, #tier4, #tier5, #tier6').hide();
function addtier() {
  if(count > countMax) {
    return;
  }
  $('#tier' + count + '').fadeIn(1000);
  count++;
}
```

Comment: You made my day, sir. Beautiful answer :) It works enough to serve my purpose. For future users however: the decrement did not work together with the remove(). I had to keep the hide() otherwise the removed elements would not reappear again. I'm new to jQuery so this could just be me overlooking something. Also just to point it out, the Math.max() with the capital Max was showing errors in the console ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it that just uses CSS selectors and doesn't need to track how many are being shown (since that's implicit in the DOM).  (Took some liberties with your `id`s and classes, so this may not fit in with your existing code)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#hide').click( function() { $('.tier:not(:hidden)').last().hide() });
  $('#show').click( function() { $('.tier:hidden').first().show() });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tier">One</div>
<div class="tier">Two</div>
<div class="tier">Three</div>
<div class="tier">Four</div>
<div class="tier">Five</div>
<div class="tier">Six</div>
<button id="hide" type="button">hide</button>
<button id="show" type="button">show</button>
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know :)